Generators Of $SO(n)$
I was wondering, for the group $SO(n)$, as far as I understand, the $n\choose 2$ infinitesimal rotations in the plane spanned by $e_i$ and $e_j$ for $0\le i<j<n$ form a basis for the corresponding Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$.  But I wonder if there exists a smaller than $n\choose 2$ set $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathfrak{so}(n)$ such that $\{\exp(tX):t\in\mathbf{R},X\in\mathcal{X}\}$ generates the whole group?

As a starting point, consider the fact that $g_1, g_2 \in \mathrm{SO}(n)$ are conjugate if and only if they rotate through the same oriented angle. So for example, $g_x^{},g_y^{},g_x^{-1} = g_z^{} \in \mathrm{SO}(3) \subseteq \mathrm{SO}(n)$, where $g_z^{}$ is the rotation by $\pi/2$ about the $z$-axis, etc. So we can certainly get away with fewer generators for $n \geq 3$.

Thanks, that is really useful!  But how would I get a smaller rotation around the $z$-axis?  If I choose a smaller angle than $\pi/2$, this equation wouldn't work, right?

This is where the smooth parameter $t$ comes in! If $g = \exp(X)$ for some $X \in \mathfrak{so}(n)$ describes a rotation about a certain axis $v$ through some angle $\theta$, then $\exp(tX)$ is a rotation about the same axis $v$ and in the same direction as $g$, but through an angle $t\theta$. Conjugation will send any small rotation to a different small rotation via the element of the group that maps one oriented axis to the other.

Ah, sorry, now I understand!  You conjugate a small rotation by a $\pi/2$ one.  Cool, thanks a lot!

Any two generic 1-parameter subgroups will generate $SO(n)$.

Is the intuition here somehow that a generic OPSG $X$ generates a $1$-dimensional dense subset, then for another such group $Y$ we have $XY$, i.e. ${xy: x\in X, y\in Y}$ generates a $2$-dimensional dense subset, $XYX$ generates a $3$-dimensional dense subset, etc.?
